# MySQL Query to retrieve maximum value among certain criteria

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have products with different rankings. The products may be members of a supergroup (like Cream).

```
product_id | supergroup | rank | other_info

1          | Cream      | 3    | Eric
2          | Zep        | 1    | Jimmy
3          | Zep        | 4    | Jon Paul
4          | Cream      | 3    | Jack
5          | Cream      | 4    | Ginger
6          | Who        | 4    | Roger
7          | Who        | 5    | John
8          | Who        | 3    | Pete
```

I want to get the max product rank from each group, along with other info for that product id. Ranks are not meant for intragroup ranks. They are ranks that work across all products in the system. So more than one product may have the same rank, even in the same group.

EDIT: fixed "other_info". I had some gibberish there. Also added a row. Results should be from highest rank to lowest. But they also should only include the highest ranking `product_id` from each `supergroup`, along with matching `other_info`.

```
product_id | supergroup | rank | other_info
2          | Zep        | 1    | Jimmy
8          | Who        | 3    | Pete
1          | Cream      | 3    | Eric
```

Can I do that with a simple query? The existing system's query already involves a GROUP BY statement on the supergroup, and no aggregators in the SELECT. That results in a random, but coherent row from within the group. What is the simplest way to modify the query to get a complete row, but always of the highest-ranked member of each super group.

If there is no way, what about this: Is this possible without GROUP BY?

Comment: Do you mean that for `Zep` supergroup rank=1 is higher than rank=4?

Comment: `more than one product may have the same rank, even in the same group`, so the query should include all the products (with same max rank) in this case, correct?

Comment: In terms of integers, I guess I mean lowest rank. I mean 1 should be retrieved instead of 3, yes.

Comment: @AzizShaikh I'eve expanded the example and fixed `other_info` in the example result set. I want to retrieve just 1 representative from each `supergroup`, the "highest ranking" (lowest integer) one. Then I want to order the results according to rank, lowest integer to highest (highest rank to lowest). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM your_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(product_id) as product_id #if there are multiple products with the same (min) rank in the same supergroup - get the one with lowest product_id
    FROM your_table tt
    JOIN (
        SELECT supergroup, MIN(rank) as min_rank
        FROM your_table
        GROUP BY supergroup
    ) mr ON mr.supergroup = tt.supergroup AND mr.min_rank = tt.rank
    GROUP BY tt.supergroup, tt.rank
) as mid ON mid.id.product_id = t.product_id
ORDER BY whatever_you_need_to
```

You need an index on `(supergroup,rank)` for this to run efficiently.

Comment: I have an index on supergroup and rank separately. I can add a composite index. I was hoping to do it without a subselect. Is that impossible?

Comment: You need a composite index. You can replace the `supergroup` one with `supergroup,rank`. It might be possible to do it without a subselect, but I doubt you will be able to make it faster. When you add the index  you should have `Using index for group-by` and two indexed JOINs in the EXPLAIN output (the rest should be the subquery stuff).

Comment: Thanks for answer and especially for specifying how to make sure my indexes are working properly. The main reason I wanted to see if I could do it without a subselect is because it is a Zend-based application and the query-building is a bit complex.